# Inject a password with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jobs

I need to pass a Jenkins password to a build agent who needs to enter it into a graphical Git login form.

I have entered my password in the Credential Manager on Jenkins but I don't know how to transmit it in the form.
I have to go through a freestyle job.

Have you had a similar case?

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCM and pass you git credentials in Jenkins Credentials Provider: Jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7kga.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).